# Laravel 5.6 using laracharts. Chart wont render

Tags: laravel, charts, chart.js

I'm trying to test out laracharts using laravel 5.6. The chart doesn't print out in the view, only the code in text form.

Controller.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use Khill\Lavacharts\Lavacharts;

class HomeController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {

        $votes  = Lava::DataTable();

        $votes->addStringColumn('Food Poll')
              ->addNumberColumn('Votes')
              ->addRow(['Tacos',  rand(1000,5000)])
              ->addRow(['Salad',  rand(1000,5000)])
              ->addRow(['Pizza',  rand(1000,5000)])
              ->addRow(['Apples', rand(1000,5000)])
              ->addRow(['Fish',   rand(1000,5000)]);

        Lava::BarChart('Votes', $votes);

        $data['votes'] = Lava::BarChart('Votes', $votes);


        return view('pages/home', $data);
    }
}
```

view

```
@section('content')

@barchart('Votes', 'poll_div')


@endsection
```

This is the output in my view. No chart only code.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
<?= $lava->render('Votes', 'poll_div'); ?>``
```

Use This in View.